# How to run .NET Core project using pythonnet on IIS

Tags: c#, python, iis, python.net

I'm trying to setup a .NET Core project using IIS(Internet Information Services). The project uses [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to call functionalities written on Python. When I start the IIS site, and send a post request to it, I get this exception. [image]

I have added the Path environment variable to the site environment variables.
I have tried changing the permissions to the Python folder.

The project works fine when started in Visual Studio 2019 using IIS Express. I'm expecting it to work the same way as on the hosted IIS server.

Comment: Hi have you installed pythonnet on the hosted server?

Comment: It is compiled for .NET Core and the dll is attached as Dependency to the project.

Comment: Could you share some details about the server configuration, such as whether you have configured it yourself or it is an Azure server for instance?

Comment: There are fundamental differences between IIS Express and IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So "I'm expecting it to work the same way as on the hosted IIS server" is impossible. Talk to the original developers of that library and see what they recommend.

Comment: I have configured it myself. Also tested the project started in Visual Studio 2019 using IIS Express with the same Python installation and everything work as intended.

Comment: @Lex Li I understand that there are fundamental differences between them, but my intent was to say that I expect the same response to my POST request from my .NET Core site.

Comment: @Lex Li Also changed the IIS account permissions to the Python Installation folder have full permissions, thats when I started getting that exception from the python interpreter I guess.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the advice, but the project is already big and also for my case of running Python code from .NET (to be used with tensorflow and other machine learning libaries) after long research found out thet pythonnet is the best solution for my situation. I believe that there is simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. The problem was indeed with the permissions so I just switched The Application Pool Identity to Custom account and entered the Administrator account. Everything seems to work as intended now.
[image]